# Array of input from HTML

Tags: html, django

I am working with django 1.8.

I have the following input form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <h1>Post Requirements</h1>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="{% url 'recruiter:create_requirement' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
            {% for i in num_reqs %}
                <h2>Requirement {{i}}</h2>
                <label for="profession">Profession</label>
                <select name="profession">
                    {% for profession in professions %}
                        <option value="{{profession.id}}">{{profession.profession}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
                <br/>
                <label for="sub_profession">Sub Profession</label>
                <select name="sub_profession">
                    {% for sub_profession in sub_professions %}
                        <option value="{{sub_profession.id}}">{{sub_profession.subprofession}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
                <br/>
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input id="title" type="text" name="title">
                <br/>
            {% endfor %}
            <input type="submit" value="Create">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

On submitting the form, I get the the `QueryDict` in the following format:

```
<QueryDict: {u'profession]': [u'1', u'2'],
             u'title': [u'Needed actor for Telugu feature film', u'Needed actor for Tamil ad film'],
             u'sub_profession': [u'1', u'2']}>
```

My expected format is:

```
<QueryDict: {u'requirements': [
                    {u'profession': u'1',
                    u'title': u'Needed actor for Telugu feature film',
                    u'sub_profession': u'1'},
                    {u'profession': u'1',
                    u'title': u'Needed actor for Tamil ad film',
                    u'sub_profession': u'2'}
                    ]}>
```

How can I modify my HTML to get the desired `QueryDict`.

Comment: Read about [`InlineFormSet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets)

Comment: You should use django form to handle the html instead of hand-make form.https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#building-a-form

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure modifying the Html would yield you the desired Querydict. I would suggest you to use javascript to post.  So in that case you can package the data as you want it finally JSONify the result and post.